# Pandas - changing rows where less than n subsequent values are equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col":[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]})
```

Now I would like to set all the rows equal to zero where less than four `1`'s appear "in a row", i.e. I would like to have the following resulting DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col":[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]})
```

I was not able to find a way to achieve this nicely...

Comment: There are several similar questions. To identify the `1` blocks, use `df['col'].ne(1).cumsum()`. Then groupby those blocks and transform size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `groupby` and `where`:

```
streaks = df.groupby(df["col"].ne(df["col"].shift()).cumsum()).transform("sum")
output = df.where(streaks.ge(4), 0)

>>> output
    col
0     0
1     0
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    0
13    0
14    0
15    0
16    1
17    1
18    1
19    1
20    0
21    0
22    0
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do

```
df.loc[df.groupby(df.col.eq(0).cumsum()).transform('count')['col']<5,'col'] = 0
df
Out[77]: 
    col
0     0
1     0
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    0
13    0
14    0
15    0
16    1
17    1
18    1
19    1
20    0
21    0
22    0
```